# odometry Tutorial and Rviz

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working through the http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom tutorial. I have the code running so it is publishing odometry info. I have also done the URDF_tutorial so I have a model of my robot that I can see in Rviz. If I run both of these at the same time should I see the robot running around in circles in Rviz? Is it not that simple or does Rviz not work that way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10745/odometry-tutorial-and-rviz/) by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are publishing the transformation between your robot and the odometry, yes. So if your robot has the base called /base_link, your odometry should publish from /odom to /base_link and of course broadcast this transformation in tf.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ringo42](https://answers.ros.org/users/651/ringo42/) on 2011-07-27**:
THanks, I got it . The trick was to change the Fixed Frame to odom, then it started moving.